Finiteness of rational double point
Let $(R,\mathfrak{m
})$ be a three dimensional complete local ring over a field $k$ of arbitrary characteristic and let $f\in R$ and $R/f$ is a rational double point.
My question is as follows.
Are there a natural number $n$ satisfying the condition below?
For any $g\in R$ s.t $f-g\in m^n$, $R/g$ is a rational double point.

Yes, this is Tougeron's theorem: you can take $n=\mu +1$, where $\mu $ is the Milnor number of $f$. An accessible reference is Singularities of
Differentiable Maps I by
Arnold, Gusein-Zade and Varchenko, §6.3.

Thanks.
In this situation, R may be singular.
Does  Tougeron's theorem hold even in this situation?

Oops, sorry I missed that. I don't know any formulation of Tougeron's theorem in the singular set-up.

I think the “finite determinacy” theorems of Arnold still apply.  The rings involved are local complete intersection rings.  I think that is the setting of Arnold’s theorems.  I will try to find a reference (maybe Mike Artin’s Tata lectures).
